# How to set the menu bar to the bottom of the window about tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to place the menu component in container `f` at the bottom of the window, but it failed.

Here is code:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
f=Frame(root)
f.pack(side='bottom')

menu=Menu(f)
menu.add_command(label='filename')
menu.add_command(label='editname')

f.config(menu=menu)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: From the docs: _...menu widget can either be used as a pop-up window or applied to a toplevel_. So you can't attach it to a `Frame`.

Comment: "but it failed" is not precise enough, does it throw an error? If yes, include the traceback, otherwise describe what you get compared to what you want. Given your code I think it gives a "TclError: widget has no attribute menu" since, like Henry Yik said, you cannot attach a menu to a frame, only to a Toplevel or Tk instance